# On direct product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group, $H$ and $K$ are two normal subgroups of $G$ with the property that $G=HK$ and $H\cap K=1$.

> Prove that $$\left(\left|H\right|,\left|K\right|\right)=1\Leftrightarrow\forall A\leq G,A=\left(A\cap H\right)\left(A\cap K\right)$$

About Dummit & Foote, Abstract Algebra, page 171:

- Each elementof $HK$ can be written uniquely as a product of $hk$, for some $h\in H$ and $k\in K$.
- $HK\cong H\times K$.

Maybe it's usefull.

Comment: What are your thoughts and efforts on the problem so far?

Comment: Please don't dump questions here with no source, no indication of why they're of interest to you, and no sign of any effort on your part.

Comment: Which direction of the proof do you have problems with?

Comment: Unfortunately, both two.

Comment: OK, here is a hint for $\Rightarrow$. Let $hk \in A$ with $h\in H$, $k \in K$. By raising to suitable powers show that $h,k \in A$. For the converse, choose a prime $p$ dividing both $|H|$ and $|K|$ and find a subgroup of order $p$ that is not in either subgroup.

Comment: Can you give me more details? Please

Comment: Maybe this post is usefull. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211185/expression-for-a-subgroup-of-a-inner-direct-product-group?rq=1

Comment: How can you raising to suitable powers of $h$ and $k$ ?

Comment: Both $h$ and $k$ are powers of $hk$. Remember that it is a direct product, so $hk=kh$.

Comment: @Alexander Gruber: I think my problem doesn't duplicate with that problem.